# My code created in React js will not store the first word into the seenWords array, and also sometimes the program will display a blank word

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

In the game, the user has 3 lives. A word is picked at random from either the initialWords array or the seenWords array. If the user clicks seen and the word has been seen, the user is awarded point. If the user clicks not seen and the word has not been displayed, the user is awarded a point. If the user is wrong, a life is deducted and a new word is displayed. Each time a word is displayed it is supposed to be put into the seenWords array.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useContext } from 'react';
import { AuthContext } from '../helpers/AuthContext';
import useSound from 'use-sound';
import correct from '../sounds/correctAns.mp3';
import incorrect from '../sounds/incorrectAns.mp3';

const WordGame = () => {
  const { authState } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const [randomWord, setRandomWord] = useState('');
  const [seenWords, setSeenWords] = useState([]);
  const [playSound] = useSound(correct, { volume: 0.25 });
  const [play] = useSound(incorrect, { volume: 0.05 });
  const [decision, setDecision] = useState(1);
  const [score, setScore] = useState(0);
  const [lives, setLives] = useState(3);

  useEffect(() => {
    getRandomWord();
  }, []); // Run once on component mount

  // Random number generator
  const getRandomNumber = (min, max) =>
    Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;

  // This function creates a random number between 0 and initialWords.length
  // and sets it as index, then whatever word is at the index of initialWords
  // array is chosen
  const getRandomWord = () => {
    console.log(seenWords);
    binaryNumGenerator();
    const initialWordsIndex = getRandomNumber(0, initialWords.length);
    const seenWordsIndex = getRandomNumber(0, seenWords.length);

    let selectedWord = null;
    if (decision === 1 || seenWords.length === 0 || seenWords.length < 3) {
      selectedWord = initialWords[initialWordsIndex];
    } else {
      selectedWord = seenWords[seenWordsIndex];
    }
    if (selectedWord == undefined) {
      setRandomWord(selectedWord);
    }

    setRandomWord(selectedWord);
  };

  const binaryNumGenerator = () => {
    // Get a random number between 0 and 1
    const randomNumber = Math.random();
    // Adjust the probability distribution
    if (randomNumber < 0.7) {
      setDecision(1); // 70% chance of getting 1
      // If 1 is returned, a word from the initialWords array
      // is selected
    } else {
      setDecision(2); // 30% chance of getting 2
      // If 2 is returned, a word from the seenWords array is
      // selected
    }
  };

  const onClickSeenHandler = () => {
    if (decision === 1) {
      setScore(score + 1);
      playSound();
      console.log('correct');
    } else {
      console.log('wrong');
      play();
      setLives(lives - 1);
    }
    getRandomWord();
  };

  const onClickNotSeenHandler = () => {
    if (seenWords.includes(randomWord)) {
      // The word has been seen before, subtract a life
      setLives(lives - 1);
      play();
    } else {
      // The word has not been seen, award a point
      setScore(score + 1);
      playSound();
      // Add the word to seenWords
      console.log(randomWord);
      setSeenWords((prevSeenWords) => [...prevSeenWords, randomWord]);
    }
    getRandomWord();
  };

  const initialWords = [
    'Apple', 'Banana', 'Elephant', 'Sunshine', 'Laptop', 'Mountain',
    'Ocean', 'Guitar', 'Symphony', 'Balloon', 'Moonlight', 'Adventure',
    // ....
    'Jubilant', 'Sanctuary', 'Cascade', 'Symphony', 'Resplendent', 'Tranquil',
  ];

  return (
    <div className={'Main Container'} >
      {lives > 0 ? (
        <div>
          <h1>Word: {randomWord}</h1>
          <h2>Score: {score}</h2>
          <h2>Lives: {lives}</h2>
          <Button variant='success' onClick={onClickSeenHandler}>
            Seen
          </Button>{' '}
          <Button variant='danger' onClick={onClickNotSeenHandler}>
            Not Seen
          </Button>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div>
          <h1>Game Over!</h1>
          <Button variant='primary' onClick={() => window.location.reload()}>
            Restart
          </Button>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default WordGame;
```

I've tried many things but nothing has worked, any help is greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Please define "nothing has worked".
What IS happening?  What errors are occurring? What have you tried to understand what's going on?

Comment: It's classic problem. You're setting state and trying to use it immediately but the new state value won't be available until the next render. You'll need to rethink your logic to take into account the asynchronous nature of React component state